# How do I get all unique names in a table and echo them out?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table like the following, I want to get all the unique people and list them. Can't go by first name because there could be multiple people with same first name. In this case there are 2 Jims.

```
id    description    username    firstname    lastname
1     blah           kim         Kim          Something
2     blah2          kim         Kim          Something
3     blah3          jim         Jim          Whatever
4     blah4          jim         Jim          Whatever
5     blah5          tim         Tim          Whoever
6     blah6          tim         Tim          Whoever
7     blah7          jim2        Jim          Persons
8     blah8          jim2        Jim          Persons
```

So the query would need to print a list like this:

```
Jim Whatever
Jim Persons
Kim Something
Tim Whoever
```

**UPDATE**

Sometimes I don't write what I tried, because I didn't try anything, and the reason I didn't try something is because it would be junk code that would never work. For example here is what I would want to do but of course this isn't the proper way to write it:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=UNIQUE") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."<br />";
}
```

**UPDATE2**

Here is what ended up working for me...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username, firstname, lastname FROM table WHERE jobid='".$_GET['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "- ".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."<br />";
}
```

I needed it to be more fine grained with the extra jobid column. I didn't mention that field before, because I knew how to add it later once I knew how to select unique records.

Comment: What is your problem? Can't you write an SQL query? (Consider `SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname FROM mytable` - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) Can't you display the results of a SQL query?

Comment: Yep, it looks like you need to use DISTINCT.

Comment: Jim Whatever has a username of jim and Jim Persons has a username of jim2.

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker for that snippet. That's what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)) complete_name 
FROM table_name;

Comment: Just says Syntax error on line 617. Doesn't say what the syntax error is.

Comment: Did you replace "complete_name" and "table_name"?

Comment: I replaced table name but didn't know what complete name was for, but it doesn't matter what name is put in that spot, there would still be a syntax error.